# Does pthread_cancel works if the thread is running blocking code like accept connection?

Tags: c

I am **beginner** to C programming I created a new thread and its working fine ,my thread blocks the code at **accept**.Does calling **pthread_cancel** from outside terminates the thread.Or do I need to **close the socket** from outside.

Inside thread code it is a blocking code

```
 while( (clientfd = accept(socketfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client,&clilen)) )
        {
                printf("New Client connected");
                ......
        }
```

Calling **pthread_cancel** from outside

```
pthread_cancel(thread_id);
```

What happens?

Comment: Take a look at [MAN](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html). It says: _Whether and when the target thread reacts to the cancellation request depends on two attributes that are under the control of that thread: its cancellability state and type._ You should read the whole description. BTW the socket still open  and you have to close it: it will not be closed automatically by thread cancellation.

Comment: @LPs MAN page says by default pthread_setcancelstate is enabled.So you are saying that I need to close the socket to stop the thread right?

Comment: No. I meant that the thread is cancelled and socket still alive. You have close it.

Comment: @Lps Ok now i understand exactly thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About the socket resource, you have to clen it up manually, because the thread cancellation will not close your resources.

You could use a cleanup_handler to do that you should look at [pthread_cleanup_push() and void pthread_cleanup_pop](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cleanup_push.3.html).

A short example could be:

```
void cleanup_handler(void *arg )
{
   printf("cleanup \n");
   // close your socket
}

void *execute_on_thread(void *arg)
{
    pthread_cleanup_push(cleanup_handler, NULL);
    pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);

    while(1)
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("Running\n");
        //thread stuff
    }

    pthread_cleanup_pop(1);

    return (void *) 0;
}

int main( )
{
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid,NULL,execute_on_thread,NULL);

    sleep(2);

    if (!pthread_cancel(tid))
    {
        pthread_join(tid, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        perror("pthread_cancel");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [open standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html) 2.9.5 section thread can be canceled at any of cancellation points. Cancellation point will occur if thread is calling `accept` function. So, you are good to go.

The socket won't be closed automatically. Only connection accepting will be canceled. Note, that port is still held by socket because the result of `bind` was not canceled. So, you still need to close your socket by `close`.

By default the tcp port won't be returned to OS immanently after socket is closed. If you want the socket to return the port right after it is closed add this lines after socket creation.

```
int flag = 1;
setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&flag, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: What about the socket did it close automatically?Because when i am trying to bind the socket to same port again after pthread_cancel() it is returning error